# Permutations and Combinations - conceptual

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Suppose we have 10 objects. I want to create a group with those 10 objects. The group should contain a minimum of 2 objects (it can contain anywhere from 2-10 members). How would I find the total number of ways in which I can do this?

If I wanted to create a group with any number of members (0-10 members), then there would be $2^{10}$ ways to do this. If the condition was that there should be a minimum of 1 member in the group, there would be $2^{10}-1$ ways to do this.
However, I'm not sure how I would do it for a minimum of 2 members?

**Edit: Considering for non-identical objects.**

Comment: To clarify:  by "group" you just mean set, no?  "Group" has a mathematical meaning which I think you do not intend.  But, even so, I don't understand what you mean.  The objects are all identical...so aren't the only possibilities $\{(x,x),(x,x,x), ..., (x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x)\}$?

Comment: Yes, the string of comments had reached unreasonable length, so we both deleted..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Number of ways to select from 10 non-identical objects:

0 - 10 objects: $2^{10},\;\text {which can also be derived as}\;{10\choose 0} + {10\choose 1} + ...{10\choose 10}$

1 - 10 objects: $2^{10} - {10\choose 0} = 2^{10} - 1$

2 - 10 objects: $2^{10} - 1 - {10\choose 1} = 2^{10} - 11$